# How to save a serialized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

I'm trying to push values onto a serialized text field (acting as array).

In the controller I have

```
class DeliveriesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @delivery = Delivery.new
end

def create
    @user = current_user
    @user.deliveries.create(params[:delivery])
    @user.recent_addresses.shift if @user.recent_addresses.size >= 10
        @user.recent_addresses.push(params[:delivery][:from_address])
    @user.save
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

end

User model

```
serialize :recent_addresses, Array
attr_accessible :recent_addresses
has_many :deliveries
```

The problem is that the user is not being saved with the new recent addresses. The from_address is being added within the controller but when I try save it rollsback and the recent addresses array is empty.

```
Parameters: {"delivery"=>{"from_address"=>"xyz"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "deliveries" ("created_at", "from_address", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 25 Oct 2013 13:21:50 UTC +00:00], ["from_address", "xyz"], ["user_id", 1]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: Try removing `attr_accessible`, Rails does this for you.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't stop the rollback

Comment: Can you post the complete controller action please.

Comment: I've included the whole controller

Comment: Change `@user.deliveries.create` to `@user.deliveries.create!` and `@user.save` to `@user.save!` this will raise an exception on errors.

Comment: I then get an error of Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters), Password confirmation can't be blank

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: No. I'm using Michael hartls tutorial

Comment: It looks like your using the devise gem. Does your user record have a password?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40008/discussion-between-dickieboy-and-spuggy)